# Windows 7 Themes on Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, themes

I often download themes from which I only use the wallpapers or some of the icons or sounds or cursors.  This is possible because, after unzipping them, what I get is a folder of all the separate parts of the theme.  However, the Windows 7 themes unzip as a single file (with a credits txt file).  Is there any way to extract the parts from that file so that I can use them on my Windows XP system?

Answer (score 1):

That file might also be zipped and therefore might be extractable. I suggest you use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to extract. Right-click the theme pack and use 7-zip’s "Extract here..." option.